# Calibarating data with Underscore.JS

Tags: underscore.js

Another task for `underscore.js` - I need to do 'calibrate' the data, for displaying it in the chart.

Given: available space: `160` and data: `data: [10, 50, 80, 90]` I want to get `calibratedData: [0, 80, 140, 160]`.

here's the algorithm:

1. get the peaks for the data, `Min=10` , `Max = 90`.
2. get the difference between `Min` and `Max`, `80`.
3. get the `Unit` space available to `1` unit of change as `160 / 80 = 2`
4. calibrate each item in data, using the ratio from the previous step as: 
   `d[i] = (d[i]-Min) * Unit`, which gives `[0, 80, 140, 160]`.

Wonder if I can accomplish the task using 'linq'able syntax of `underscore.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why people downvoted your question, but it was fun to find the answer. Here it is:

```
function calibrate( data, availableSpace ) {
    var min = _.min(data);
    var max = _.max(data);
    var range = max - min;
    var spacePerUnit = availableSpace / range;
    return _.map( data, function (value) {
        return ( value - min ) * spacePerUnit;
    });
}

alert( calibrate( [10, 50, 80, 90], 160 ) );
```

You can try it in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXwRd/).

The key is to use the `map()` function in Underscore with this function:

```
function (value) {
  return ( value - min ) * spacePerUnit;
}
```

This function has access to the min, max and spacePerUnit values in the parent function which makes it very efficient (because it doesn't do the calculations in every iteration).